# ffmpeg Error: Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not support ed by this libavformat build

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to convert group of ".jpg" files acting as individual frames into 1 single mpeg video ".mp4"

Example parameters i used:

```
frame duration  = 2 secs
frame rate      = 30  fps
encoder         = libx264 (mpeg)
input pattern   = "*.jpg"
output pattern  = video.mp4
```

Based on ffmpeg wiki instructions at (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images), I issued this command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/2 -pattern_type glob -i "*.jpg" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
[image2 @ 049ab120] Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not 
supported by this libavformat build *.jpg: Function not implemented
```

Which probably means the API pattern matching commands for my build/version have changed. By the way this my windows 32bit ffmpeg download build (`ffmpeg-20150702-git-03b2b40-win32-static`).

How can I choose a group of files using pattern matching using ffmpeg?

Comment: Why is this down voted? there are many ffmpeg questions on Stackoveflow, ffmpeg is a legitimate video encoding library & API. I have also clearly stated my problem , attempt, and question?

Comment: By the way I got this kind of working by using ffmpeg input pattern -i `img%1d.jpg` entire command `ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/2 -start_number 1 -i img%1d.jpg -vf scale=720:756 -c:v libx264 -r 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4` however this only converts the 1st five frames/JPEG images why is there a limit, How can I convert any amount of JPEGs to a MPEG video?

Comment: It's `img%01d.jpg` with a zero. It'll only match `img0.jpg` to `img9.jpg`

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/666860/clarification-for-ffmpeg-input-option-with-image-files-as-input

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`-pattern_type glob` [requires glob.h](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/6e073dd127f09f203bd21d40a1eb423afd183e7a/configure#L3988).

`glob` is defined in the POSIX standard and it's **not available on Windows** by default.

Create/rename your files using sequential file naming `image###.jpg` then use sequence wildcards like `-i image%03d.jpg` as input.

Comment: Please refer to my July 3rd comment above, I solved the original problem , however ffmpeg only encodes 1st 5 files into video , not more, that's the current issue/problem. I need to encode "N" number of frames into a larger sequence.

Comment: Your question refers to glob, please consider updating it or posting a new one. I also commented on your original question. If you need a larger sequence just use `%0n` where `n` is the number of digits. How are your files named?

Comment: As you see I already got that issue working on July 03, however it doesnt do more than 5 frames.

Comment: Then update the question and add the naming convention of your files. If you use a sequential index, is it always incremented by 1 without skipping?

Comment: Thanks it seems I was naming my files literary img01, img02, img03, etc... Instead of img1, img2, img3 , thanks for the help. Also are you familiar with actual Java API for ffmpeg , ho would I achieve the same result using API rather command line?

Comment: I actually used both Xuggler & JCodec initially which created the same output as ffmpeg , all three outputs play correctly on my PC, Mac, and , Android, however this is meant to play on a embedded device , and the only video that plays correctly on that device is the ffmpeg generated video, dont know why ,thats the reason I need to now compile ffmpeg src into ".ddl" or use "javah" option & access ffmpeg via JNI, I will post this question later today. Thanks a million buddy, but I have a ways to go now, fun , fun fun ...

Comment: `ffmpeg -framerate 15 -pattern_type sequence -start_number 00001 -i C:\Users\u\Videos\LRT_%05d.jpg -s:v 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p C:\Users\u\Videos\my-timelapse_1.mp4`

Answer (score 11):

You can write a script in Python, which supports glob module in Windows:

```
import subprocess
import glob
import os

filenames = glob.glob('*.png')
path = os.path.abspath("").replace("\\", "/")
print(path)
duration = 0.05

with open("ffmpeg_input.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for filename in filenames:
        outfile.write(f"file '{path}/{filename}'\n".encode())
        outfile.write(f"duration {duration}\n".encode())

command_line = f"ffmpeg -r 60 -f concat -safe 0 -i ffmpeg_input.txt -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p {path}\\out.mp4"
print(command_line)

pipe = subprocess.Popen(command_line, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
output = pipe.read().decode()
pipe.close()
```

Comment: but its compiling images stored in C:/users/user folder for strange reason