# Input parameters to FFMPEG

Tags: windows, shell, ffmpeg

I am trying to make an FFMPEG script that relied on a glob input pattern from Linux to Windows. Unfortunately that is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31513542/3239436) so I am looking for an alternative. I do not want to have to rename or copy the files every time I run the script because the files are used elsewhere and I cannot rename them and I would like to avoid duplication or unnecessary temporary files.

Are <s>globs</s> [numerically sequential named images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images) my only option here? Ideally I would like to input a list of image paths to FFMPEG as a substitute for `ffmpeg -i *.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I could find (that's Windows compatible) was to generate a line separated list of files in a text file and pass that through to FFMPEG. For example, to generate a stabilized MP4 from a bunch of JPEGs:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i ./files.txt -vf deshake=rx=64:ry=64 ./stabilized.mp4
```

Where `files.txt` is a list of the files in the [following format](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate). The safe option toggles the ability to have absolute/relative file paths.

```
# this is a comment
file 'C:/path/to/file1.jpg'
file 'C:/path/to/file2.jpg'
file 'C:/path/to/file3.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

The workarounds are to prepare a text file with the names and use the [concat demuxer](https://superuser.com/a/1049464/114058).

Or you can use image2pipe

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 25 -i - out.mp4
```