# ffmpeg convert images with name pattern into video

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, filenames

I am converting png images into a video using ffmpeg.

My png file names are like this:

```
image1_xy.png
image2_xy.png
image3_xy.png
image4_xy.png
...
image10_xy.png
image11_xy.png
...
image100_xy.png
image101_xy.png
...
```

my script is the following:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i image%03d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 25  -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

which is working only when the file names are like `image001.png` , `image002.png`...

How should i modify this to take into account the file name pattern I have?

### update

i don't mind if the answer suggests to use a bash script to rename files in the order they appear with the right pattern.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40872592/5726027