# how to concat multiple image paths to video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

how can i concat multiple image paths in command line and convert it into a mp4 using ffmeg. I have tried using pipe(|), space and comma too.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40872592/5726027

Comment: I am getting a plain video.

Comment: Add output option `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`).