# How to create a video from frames named using timestamp with ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, video, ffmpeg, mp4, strftime

I have a folder filled with frames that have the timestamp in the name in the folowing format

> im_%H_%M_%S_%MS.png

```
im_08_05_09_007324.png
im_08_05_09_532857.png
im_08_05_10_059340.png
im_08_05_10_575862.png
im_08_05_11_118361.png
im_08_05_11_596814.png
im_08_05_12_148340.png
im_08_05_12_665838.png
```

I try to use `-pattern_type glob` in windows but it does not work.

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i im_*.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"  -pix_fmt yuv420p $videoName
```

I get

```
 Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not supported by this libavformat build im_*.png: Function not implemented
```

later I found that this do not work on windows :( which is what I am using. [ffmpeg Error: Pattern type 'glob' was selected but globbing is not support ed by this libavformat build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201164/ffmpeg-error-pattern-type-glob-was-selected-but-globbing-is-not-support-ed-by)

I also try

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 10 -pattern_type glob -i im_%02d_%02d_%02d_%06d.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2"  -pix_fmt yuv420p $videoName
```

I got

```
im_%02d_%02d_%02d_%06d.png: No such file or directory
```

I am running out of ideas. I refuse to believe that there is no way to do this in ffmpeg and powershell.
I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a workaround, via the concat demuxer

Create a text file with the list of filenames in order

```
file im_08_05_09_007324.png
file im_08_05_09_532857.png
file im_08_05_10_059340.png
file im_08_05_10_575862.png
file im_08_05_11_118361.png
```

and then run

```
ffmpeg -f concat -r 10 -i list.txt -c:v libx264 ...
```

(this will produce warnings about invalid DTS but you can ignore them)

Comment: Thank you very much!! Sorry for my late answer. I was in a hurry that day and decided to created the videos with Fiji imageJ. However, now that I need to create lot of videos, I found the necessity to create a script. Building on your answer I wrote my full solution.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Mulvya solution I wrote a powershell script that will create the txt with filename in the suggested format.

1. Create a txt file with directory png content

   ```
   $inFolder = "C:\my_folder_with_Png_frames\"
   $inSearch = $inFolder+"*.png"
   $outFile  = $inFolder + "framenames.txt"
   Get-childitem -path $inSearch -recurse -name | Out-File $outFile -Encoding ASCII
   ```

I added the `Encoding` on the Out-File cmdlet, since the default is `UTF-8-BOM` and `ffmpeg` does not like it.

2. Pre-append the string "file " to each line of the txt file.

   ```
   $prependVar = "file "
   $lines      = get-content $outFile
   $newlines   = $lines | ForEach-Object{ "$prependVar$_"}
   $newlines | Out-File $outFile -Encoding ASCII
   ```
3. Call FFMPEG

   ```
    cd $inFolder
    C:/ffmpeg/bin.\ffmpeg.exe -f concat -r 10 -i $outFile -c:v libx264 -r 30  -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
   ```

Steps 1. and 2. will not produce a txt file with fullpath names. Only the names. This is why we need to `cd` to the folder.

Comment: Hey, I am trying to do something similar to what you have here and it is reading my filename 'file myjpegfile.jpg'  wron somehow. I get an error "Impossible to open file 'Dmyjpegfile.jpg" For some reason it is appending on a 'D' that doesn't exist. I am guessing it is a format issue, but I am using the ASCII Encoding so I am not sure what is causing it.